# How to use a TypeScript method decorator and retain normal `this` scope

Tags: typescript, ts-node, typescript-decorator

PLEASE NOTE: This issue was because of the use of GraphQL resolvers in running my decorated method. It meant that the scope of `this` was `undefined`. However, the basics of the question are useful for anyone hitting a problem with decorators.

---

This is a basic decorator I'm wanting to use (mine has more code in it):

```js
const someDecorator = (argPassed: any) => {

  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    // DO stuff here...
    console.log(argPassed);

    // Wrapping the original method
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => {

      const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);

      return result;
    };
  };
};
```

I am using arrow functions within the decorator which is the only way i could get it to return some kind of scope, albeit different to a normal `this` scope.

This is the class I'm using and the method I'm decorating:

```js
class SomeClass {

  constructor() {
  }

  @someDecorator('Passing this in...')
  public doingSomething(argPassed: string) {

    console.log(this); // Returns: { default: SomeClass { otherMethodInMyClass: [Function] } }

    //  Meaning i can't do this
    //  this.otherMethodInMyClass is not a function
    this.otherMethodInMyClass(argPassed);

  }

  private otherMethodInMyClass = (argPassed: any) => {
    // Let's go for it...
  }

}
```

Currently the decorator passes back the scope of `doingSomething` as:

```
{ default: SomeClass { otherMethodInMyClass: [Function] } }
```

When not using the decorator I get:

```
SomeClass { doingSomething: [Function], otherMethodInMyClass: [Function] }
```

Is this normal behaviour? If not, what am I doing wrong?
If so, how do I allow my method to use its own scope as I am calling other methods after.

Update:
As @jcalz rightly mentioned, an arrow function doesn't get its own `this` context. However when I used a non-arrow function across the decorator `this` returned as `undefined`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use an arrow function as a method, since [an arrow function does not get its own `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).  Use a regular anonymous function instead.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I tried without arrow functions, and just got undefined back for this.

Comment: Also @jcalz, If you have a working example where this returns as the correct context, please drop it as the answer!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue in your question seems to be that you're using an arrow function as a method, which is not advisable since [arrow functions don't get their own `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

You went on to say that changing this doesn't fix your issue, but I can't reproduce that:

```
const someDecorator = (argPassed: any) => {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        console.log("ARGPASSED: ");
        console.log(argPassed);
        // anonymous function, not arrow
        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
            return result;
        };
    };
};

class SomeClass {    
    constructor() { }

    @someDecorator('Passing this in...')
    public doingSomething(argPassed: string) {   
        console.log("THIS: ")
        console.log(this); 
        this.otherMethodInMyClass(argPassed);
    }

    private otherMethodInMyClass = (argPassed: any) => { }
}

new SomeClass().doingSomething("abc");
// ARGPASSED: 
// Passing this in...
// THIS: 
// Object { otherMethodInMyClass: otherMethodInMyClass() }
```

[Link to code in Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20someDecorator%20%3D%20(argPassed%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20originalMethod%20%3D%20descriptor.value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22ARGPASSED%3A%20%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(argPassed)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20anonymous%20function%2C%20not%20arrow%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.value%20%3D%20function%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20originalMethod.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20SomeClass%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40someDecorator('Passing%20this%20in...')%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doingSomething(argPassed%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22THIS%3A%20%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.otherMethodInMyClass(argPassed)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20otherMethodInMyClass%20%3D%20(argPassed%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20SomeClass().doingSomething(%22abc%22)%3B%0A%2F%2F%20ARGPASSED%3A%20%0A%2F%2F%20Passing%20this%20in...%0A%2F%2F%20THIS%3A%20%0A%2F%2F%20Object%20%7B%20otherMethodInMyClass%3A%20otherMethodInMyClass()%20%7D)

Looks good to me.  If your issue persists, you might want to include more details about your configuration in your question.  It always helps to make sure that code in your questions constitutes a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Good luck!

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it answers the question as I asked it. I have now worked out that the actual issue is the manner in which i am calling my method. I am calling it as part of a GraphQL resolver which is changing the scope before the method is even run. So when run directly, `this` is `defined`, when via a resolver `this` is `undefined`. Thanks for your help @jcalz.

Comment: just a curious question here, What if I replace `this` here with `target` what will be the pit falls ?

`const result = originalMethod.apply(this -> target, args);`

Comment: You can [try it](https://tsplay.dev/w62XGw) and see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using methods of a class as GraphQL resolvers, and the only way I was able to get around the problem was to use the class as a singleton, and then calling the other private methods from the singleton instead of *this*.