# Invoking a function from a decorator while keeping the "this" context from the original class of the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to execute a decorated function whenever something inside the decorator itself happens. My attempt already does that, but loses the execution context meanwhile. The `this` keyword becomes `undefined` in the original function.

My decorator looks like this:

```
export const MyDecorator = <T>() => {

    return ( target: T, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor ) => {

        const originalMethod: ( ...args: any ) => unknown = descriptor.value;

        /* Something happened, execute function */
        setTimeout(() => {
            originalMethod.call(this);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I've applied the decorator to a function inside a class:

```
class MyClass {

    @MyDecorator()
    public myMethod() {
        console.log('I got executed!');
        console.log(this); /* undefinied */
    }
}
```

I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189503/how-to-use-a-typescript-method-decorator-and-retain-normal-this-scope) before, but it doesn't talk about actually invoking the function from the decorator, but rather changing the behavior of the original function. Changing the arrow functions to anonymous functions didn't work for me. Perhaps I have missed something crucial?

Comment: Your decorator doesn't really decorate the class, all it does is to (attempt to) execute the method from a timeout *when the class is defined*. Is that intended?

Comment: Once you fix that, you'll probably run into the issue you found already. *Which* of the many arrow functions did you change to a normal `function`?

Comment: @Bergi yes that is intended. I don't want a class decorator, I want a [method decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators) instead

Comment: @Bergi I've tried to change all of my arrow functions to a anonymous functions. The factory and the function inside the factory aswell.

Comment: Yes, it's a method decorator - and it is called when the method is *defined*, when the class definition is executed. At that time, there is no instance available on which you could call a method. [What do you actually want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), what is that "*Something happened*"? Is this your real code?

Comment: `originalMethod.call(target);`

Comment: @Bergi the ``setTimeout`` is hypothetical. In my real code it is replaced with an event listener. Every time that event listener broadcasts and event, then I want to execute the decorated function after some preperations inside the decorator.

Comment: @hoangdv it seems like this doesn't work as expected. Please have a look at [this example](https://cutt.ly/umdUDAV). My variable ``test`` is returned as undefined.

Comment: @SlateDave Ok, please [edit] your question to include the actual code. And the question remains: When do you want to install the event listener (or: start the timeout)? When the method is called? Or when an instance is created? And what `target` instance do expect the method to be called on when an event happens? It's not a function, it's a method. Or did you actually mean to use a `static` method?